# SyntaxError: Unexpected token . when trying to get process.env node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to implement elasticsearch

```
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const hbs = require('hbs');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const fs = require('fs');

const sslRedirect = require('heroku-ssl-redirect');
const elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

var app = express();

// elasticsearch
var connectionString = process.env.SEARCHBOX_URL;
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    hosts: connectionString
  } else {
    hosts: ['http://localhost:9200']
  }
});

client.ping({
  requestTimeout: 30000,
}, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.error('elasticsearch cluster is down!');
  } else {
    console.log('Everything is ok');
  }
});
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

I have taken a look at how I'm getting the env in various places and I'm doing it the same way. So not sure why the error is throwing here.

Comment: Your `if` is in an object literal, not a code block. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Use a tool to validate your code as you type it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is invalid. If you need conditional use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
const client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  hosts: isProduction ? connectionString : ['http://localhost:9200']
});
```

Comment: In other words, you cannot use arbitrary code as object key.

Comment: Gotcha, I shall bare this in mind thank you. I shall mark as answered when it becomes available.